# How can I identify duplicated elements in rows

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a data frame which looks like this but with altogether 31 variables(columns) and 11000 observations (the missing values are empty):

```
T1 = c("a1", "c1", "e1", "d1", "a3", "f1", "f2") 
T2 = c("b1", "d1", "a1", "b2", "a3", "f1", "f3")
T3 = c(NA, NA, "e1", "d1", NA, "a4", "f3")
T4 = c( NA, NA, NA, "b2", NA, "b3", "f5")
T5 = c( NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "a4", "f6")
T6 = c( NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  NA, "f7") 
T7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "c1")
T8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "c1")
T9 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "f2")
T10= c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "f3")
```

I would like to identify if there is any duplicated element of the "T" type variables by rows, so my df would look like this:

```
 T1 = c("a1", "c1", "e1", "d1", "a3", "f1", "f2") 
 T2 = c("b1", "d1", "a1", "b2", "a3", "f1", "f3")
 T3 = c(NA, NA, "e1", "d1", NA, "a4", "f3")
 T4 = c( NA, NA, NA, b2, NA, "b3", "f5")
 T5 = c( NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "a4", "f6")
 T6 = c( NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  NA, "f7") 
 T7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "c1")
 T8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "c1")
 T9 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "f2")
 T10= c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "f3")
 D = c(F, F, T, T, T, T, T)
```

I attempted to write a function but clearly I miss something because it does not work:
first I created a new variable with empty values

```
df$D <- ""
```

then the function:

```
dupl <- function(x){
     for(i in 1:nrow(x))
              if (duplicated(x[i], incomparables = NA)){
            df$D <- "TRUE"
  }else{
    df$D <- "FALSE"
  }
}

df$D <- dupl(df)
```

I also tried this code but it does not give me the rows (when D takes a value of true) which contains the duplicated elements:

```
df$D <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(i) any(duplicated(i, incomparables = NA)))
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the example.  The values `a1`, `c1` etc are strings and needs quoting.  You can check by copy/pasting the code into the R console and see if it works  An option is `apply(df1, 1, FUN = function(x) anyDuplicated(x[x!=""]))`

Comment: Thanks to you both for the comments, now the last code works, still do not know what is wrong with the function but I assume that the main thing is that there is a solution. I deleted the other columns from my original data and forgot to include the id column but in the code I counted with it, this is why I did not get the correct data. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually I used the code I put it on myself just needed to correct it, but from the answers I would prefer the second one so I chose that one. Cannot indicate usefulness because I am new to this and I have low points of reputation (however I did, it is just not showed here). And yes, I am still learning the rules of game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses base R only.

```
df1$D <- apply(df1, 1, function(x) {
  x <- na.omit(x)
  any(unlist(Map('==', x[1], x[-1])))
})

df1
#  T1 T2   T3   T4   T5   T6   T7   T8   T9  T10     D
#1 a1 b1 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> FALSE
#2 c1 d1 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> FALSE
#3 e1 a1   e1 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  TRUE
#4 d1 b2   d1   b2 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  TRUE
#5 a3 a3 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  TRUE
#6 f1 f1   a4   b3   a4 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  TRUE
#7 f2 f3   f3   f5   f6   f7   c1   c1   f2   f3  TRUE
```

**Data.**

With the vectors in the question, the data.frame is created with the following code. It uses a function from external package `stringr`.

```
v <- stringr::str_sort(ls(pattern = '^T[[:digit:]]+$'), numeric = TRUE)
df1 <- data.frame(mget(v))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of `dplyr` and `tidyverse` which is why I would go this route:

```
df <- data.frame(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10)

df %>% 
mutate(index = row_number()) %>% 
gather(key, value, -index, na.rm = T) %>% 
group_by(index) %>% 
summarise(D = any(duplicated(value))) %>%
cbind(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am relatively new to R so I do not know how  to get an object of D from this code. It would be difficult to analyse the 11000 rows.

Comment: No, I just do not know how to use your code in order to add the result into my df. I can get the answer in the console but I need it as a new variable in the df. Using this code gives the result the way I wanted:    df$D <- apply(df, 1, function(i) any(duplicated(i, incomparables = NA)))

Comment: So I added `cbind` which will add this to your `df`.